# Git rebase or merge not detecting changed files

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-merge, git-rebase

I forked a repository from some other person. I am working on a branch `develop` on my forked repo. I check out a new branch from it named `issue`. I did some changes in the new branch `issue` and pushed it.

Then I realized that the `develop` branch in the remote repo got updated, and so I pull the changed into my local branch `develop` which just deleted some of the files. Now I want to merge those changes into the `issue` branch.

1. I did `git rebase develop` inside the `issue` branch. But it said that it is already updated with the `develop` branch.
2. I also tried pulling directly from the remote repo inside the `issue` branch, and it also said that it is up-to-date with that repo.
3. I tried `git merge develop` similar to the `rebase` command, and it also gave the same result.

I have checked that those files are already being tracked by git.
I don't want to manually delete those files.

I did `git fetch origin develop` from the remote repo and then `git reset --hard HEAD` inside the `issue` branch, which deleted the changes I made in other files.

What is the problem here, and can someone suggest an alternative to this without losing changes and without creating a new branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct approach is:

```bash
git fetch
git switch issue
git rebase origin/develop
```

Meaning:

- no need to update the local `develop` branch itself, the remote tracking branch `origin/develop` is enough (and is updated by `git fetch`)
- no need to merge `develop` (an integration branch) to another branch (like `issue`): integrations branches are branches you are merging ("integrating") *to*, *not* from.
- as long as the `issue` branch did not update the files deleted in the `develop` branch, those files will remain deleted.

Note: With Git 2.23+ (Q3 2019), `git checkout` is replaced here with [`git switch` (presented here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309).